# Loop thru array of Puppeteer elements and further parse each one

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Aw man, I have been trying to work with this for a long time and I'm so stuck.

I need to walk a series of DOM objects, and extract info from each using XPath selectors. My source HTML does not have any identifying IDs or classes on its elements so there's a lot of walking.

Here's some (very simplified) sample code. The goal is to get a list of LI elements, then use more selectors on each of the elements to extract the names inside the spans.

Simplified sample code: (https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/)

```
const html = '
<html> <ul>
    <li>
        <div> <span>Joe</span> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div> <span>Bob</span> </div>
    </li>
</ul> </html>';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto( `data:text/html,${html}` );

// now wait for a sec for the list to be populated
let arrayOfNames = await page.evaluate( async ( page ) => {
    let results = [];
    let ulElements = await page.$x( '//ul' );
    // strangely, I get back an object here, though shouldn't I get back an array?

    console.log( 'Got list of UL elements: ', ulElements );

    // loop through each item we found with selector above
    ulElements.forEach( async ( item ) => {
        let oneItem = await item.$x( '//li/div' );

        name = oneItem.$eval( 'span', element => element.innerText );

        console.log( 'We found ' + name );

        results.push( name );
    } );

    return results;
}, page );

// if it worked, arrayOfNames = ['Joe', 'Bob']
```

(Yes, I know I can accomplish the task easier with this sample HTML. But the real HTML I am parsing is crazy-complex. This is just a simplified look at my problem.)

The code above fails, saying I have some kind of circular DOM reference. I can't figure out why... I've been googling... I'm not even sure why and how I'm using evaluate() in one place, $eval in another, and then I also read about evaluateHandler... it's so confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can use Puppeteer API inside `page.evaluate()`: it executes its function argument code in the pure browser context, so try to use just Web API here. Here are two equivalent ways (with selectors and XPath) to achieve your goal:

```js
'use strict';

const html = `
<html> <ul>
    <li>
        <div> <span>Joe</span> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div> <span>Bob</span> </div>
    </li>
</ul> </html>`;

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const arrayOfNames = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const results1 = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('ul li > div span'),
        span => span.innerText,
      );

      const results2 = [];
      const xpathList = document.evaluate(
        '//ul//li/div//span',
        document.body, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null,
      );
      for (let i = 0; i < xpathList.snapshotLength; i++) {
        results2.push(xpathList.snapshotItem(i).innerText);
      }

      return [results1, results2];
    });

    console.log(arrayOfNames);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

And two equal results:

```
[ [ 'Joe', 'Bob' ], [ 'Joe', 'Bob' ] ]
```